# Assigning double * to V[3]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, function-pointers

I have a function which returns `double *`

```
double* addVectors( double* vec1, double* vec2 ) 
{
    double vec[3];
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        vec[i] = vec1[i] + vec2[i];

    return vec;
}
```

How can I assign the result of `addVectors` to an array? I did the following but I am sure there is a professional way of doing it.

```
double A[3] = {1, 2, 3};
double B[3] = {4, 5, 6};
double C[3];

double *val = addVectors( A, B );
C[0] = val[0];
C[1] = val[1];
C[2] = val[2];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addVectors` returns a pointer to a local array, when `addVectors` returns `val` becomes garbage data.

you could pass in third parameter to `addVectors`, you need to make sure all `vec` have at least 3 elements though:

```
void addVectors( double* vec1, double* vec2, double* vec) 
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        vec[i] = vec1[i] + vec2[i];
}

double A[3] = {1, 2, 3};
double B[3] = {4, 5, 6};
double C[3] = {};         // initialize all C elements to 0.0

addVectors(A,B,C);
```

My Suggestion is use STL container like [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [std::list etc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), or use [st::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if C++11 is enabled.

With STL container could archive your intention:

```
std::vector<double> addVectors(const std::vector<double>& v1, 
                               const std::vector<double>& v2)
{
    std::vector<double> v;

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) 
    {
        v.push_back(v1[i] + v2[i]);
    }

    return v;
}


int main()
{

    std::vector<double> A = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<double> B = {4, 5, 6};

    std::vector<double> C(3, 0.0);

    std::vector<double> D = addVectors(addVectors(A,B),C);

    for(auto& e : D)
    {
        cout << e << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I defined the function to return `double *` is that I want to be able to use the function like `addVectors(addVectors(A,B),C)`.

Comment: then you should use vector or std::array

Comment: seems `array` would be more appropriate since the size doesn't change

Comment: @claptrap it depends on if he has C++11 or not!

Comment: I used the first approach `void addVectors( double* vec1, double* vec2, double* vec)` and it was very fast.

Answer (score 1):

one other way to do return an array from a function is to embed it into a struct because then the contents will be copied:

```
typedef struct
{
  double vec[3];
} vecret;


vecret addVectors( double* vec1, double* vec2 ) 
{
  vecret V;
  double vec[3];
  for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  {
      V.vec[i] = vec1[i] + vec2[i];
  }
  return V;
}
```